# Empty value when pushing form field data into a locally stored array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I have an empty array that is connected to local storage. I want to push data from a form field into the array when the form is submitted. It recognizes that I am pushing data in the console as it logs the array value as [] and then "" once I click the submit button instead of the inputted text from the form field

```
        <form id="player-name-form">
            <input
            class="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="player 1"
            id="player1"
            required
            maxlength="50"
            >
            <button id="confirm-player-1" type="submit" onclick="formBtnClick()" >confirm player 1</button>
        </form>
```

```
// Setting player names to local storage
let playerNames = [];
let form = document.getElementById('player-name-form');
let formBtn = document.getElementById('confirm-player-1');
this.name = form.player1.value;
localStorage.setItem("playerNames", JSON.stringify(playerNames));

// Adding form input to local storage
function formBtnClick () {
 event.preventDefault()
localStorage.setItem("playerNames", JSON.stringify(this.name));
}
```

I'd like the form generated 'this.name' value to log in the locally stored array

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Use `onsubmit` on the form instead of `onclick` on the button

Comment: You never push any items to the array

Comment: `this.name` is set once at the beginning before any value is inside the input field, then you push that empty value to the local storage

Answer (score 0):

You can write this script

```js
export function formBtnClick() {
    let form = document.getElementById('player-name-form');
    const name = form.player1.value;
    const prevValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("playerNames"));
    const names = [...prevValue, name];
    localStorage.setItem("playerNames", JSON.stringify(names));
    form.player1.value = '';
}

export function setEmptyArray() {
    let playerNames = [];
    localStorage.setItem("playerNames", JSON.stringify(playerNames));
}

const initialValue = localStorage.getItem("playerNames");
if(!initialValue) {
    setEmptyArray();
}
```

and the following html

```html
<button onclick="setEmptyArray()">SET empty array as names</button>
<form id="player-name-form" >
    <input
            name="player1"
            class="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="player 1"
            id="player1"
            required
            maxlength="50"
    >
    <button id="confirm-player-1" onclick="formBtnClick()" type="button">confirm player 1</button>
</form>
```

List of changes:

- to input added attribute "name" to get this input easily
- type changed from submit to button to prevent page reload
- login splitted to setting and resetting local storage values